# Was Disney's The Black Hole the last film to feature an overture?

Tags: soundtrack, the-black-hole

I have a soft spot for 1979's *The Black Hole* and, in particular, John Barry's beautiful score for it. It appears that this film, plus *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* (in the same year) were the last films to feature a short overture at the beginning - were there any other films after these two that featured overtures?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe [Midnight in Paris](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1605783/) (2011) had an overture, if I remember correctly.

Wikipedia has a nice [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_with_overtures#After_1970) of films containing overtures, including a post-1970 section. I can't imagine that it's completely exhaustive, so I'm sure that there are films with overtures missing from the list. But the short answer to your question is no - *The Black Hole* was not the last film to feature an overture.

Comment: Thank you! Guess I was too lazy to go do a little wiki research ;)

Comment: @Neil it happens to the best of us! I was actually quite surprised to find that they've got an entire page devoted to exactly this question.